# What can happen on the "other side" of Berezinskii–Kosterlitz–Thouless (BKT) transition?

Tags: solid-state-physics, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

There is a generalized concept of [Berezinskii–Kosterlitz–Thouless (BKT) transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosterlitz%E2%80%93Thouless_transition)  in any dimension [not just in 2 dimensional classical system or 1+1 dimensional quantum system], such that the correlation length $\xi$ diverges, at the critical point $\alpha_c$ by tunning a certain parameter $\alpha$ near $\alpha_c$, as
$$
\xi \propto L \exp(\frac{c}{\sqrt{\alpha_c-\alpha}}),
$$
while the mass scale $m$ goes as its inverse:
$$
m \propto M \exp(-\frac{c}{\sqrt{\alpha_c-\alpha}}),
$$
where $M\sim 1/L$. (In the usual BKT in 2d thermal phase transition, the $\alpha$ parameter can be a temperature $T$.)

(Note that, the derivative respect to $\alpha$ on the correlation length diverges, for all orders, including to the infinite order of its derivative.)

However, the above formula works for $\alpha < \alpha_c$.

> My question is that **what happens to the "other side" of BKT transition, when $\alpha > \alpha_c$?**  Is there a generic/specific constraint on the other side $\alpha > \alpha_c$? Or does it have no restriction on $\alpha > \alpha_c$? What is the physical intuition behind approaching from the othe side?

In certain cases, I know that we consider the usual BKT as its inverse of $\xi$, the mass scale as:
$$
m \propto M \exp(-\frac{c}{\sqrt{|\alpha_c-\alpha|}}) \theta({\alpha_c-\alpha}),
$$
where $\theta({\alpha_c-\alpha})$ is a theta function strictly being zero on the other side, when $\alpha > \alpha_c$. Does this also imply that the correlation length must diverge as well on the other side:
$$
\xi \propto L \exp(\frac{c}{\sqrt{|\alpha_c-\alpha|}}) \frac{1}{\theta({\alpha_c-\alpha})}?
$$

> Is this a general situation, or can there be (more) other possibilities on the other side?